# How to route new action with params in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 models: `User` and `Post`
`User` has many `posts`
`Post` belongs to `User`

Then I created a new action named `list` in `PostsController`, it takes user's `id` as params to find and list all posts posted by certain user.

The URL is like `posts/list/:user_id`

How can I modify routes to perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your routes

```
match 'posts/list/:user_id', :to => 'posts#list'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me this time.  It's weird, because I tried but failed.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, go to the config folder then open routes.rb and uncomment the following line (or add it if it doesn't exist):

```
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: did you restart your rails app after doing this?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't work. Thank you very much for your help.